# How to extract data from <td> cols into an array using bash?

Tags: bash, html-table, extract

I have managed to extract data from a website, then get relevant data from the extracted webpage. Now I am stuck as to how to extract data from `<td>` cols. into an array for data manipulation ?

My extracted HTML is following:

```html
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                    <td>abc3207</td>
<td>151</td>
<td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
<td>Off Campus</td>
<td>OFF</td>
<td>12 of 999 </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="http://lorem.com/test?id=abc3207&amp;year=2015" target="_blank">Get</a></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>abc3207</td>
<td>151</td>
<td>Dolor Sit Amet</td>
<td>Mount Lawley</td>
<td>ON</td>
<td>45 of 999 </td>
<td><a href="http://lorem.com//lookup?sq_content_src=asas">Activity</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><a href="http://lorem.com/test?id=abc3207&amp;year=2015" target="_blank">Get</a></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
```

I am doing this using a bash script as I must do it via bash only.

Comment: have you considered using regex in your script?

Comment: "bash only" means you've constrained yourself to the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

To parse html or xml, you'd better use dedicated command line tools as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

But with your html sample, you can try this :

```
mapfile td < <(sed -n 's/[\t ]*<td[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/td>/\1/p' file)
for td in "${td[@]}"; do
  printf "$td"
done
```

sed extracts all td contents and pass the result to mapfile using  [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

`mapfile` stores each line from the process substitution in an array variable named `$td`.

It will work with your simple html with :

- one `td` tag per line
- opening and closing `td` on same line

Comment: `printf "$td"` is buggy -- if there were a `%` sign in the literal text it would be treated as a format string; a backslash would be treated as an escape sequence; etc. Better to use `printf '%s\n' "$td"` (or, if you explicitly *want* to map escape sequences, `printf '%b\n' "$td"` -- which is actually suggested as a preferred pattern, replacing `echo`s which honor such sequences, in [the relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html); see the "APPLICATION USAGE" section). And `printf '%s\n' "${td[@]}"` would be an easier way to print all the results.